# Compare Columns from Separate Schema in SQL using TOAD Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I am trying to extract data via a unique identifier from two separate schema in TOAD for Oracle using SQL. Normally, I would export to Python and work the csv from there, however, in this case, I must compare in TOAD before export as one data field is WAY too large to export without filtering down using the ticket identifier. So, I have tried:

```
SELECT LDKEY, LDOWNERTABLE, LDTEXT, LDOWNERCOL
FROM DB.SCHEMA1 
WHERE LDKEY = DB.SCHEMA2.TICKETUID
```

and...

```
SELECT LDKEY, LDOWNERTABLE, LDTEXT, LDOWNERCOL
FROM DB.SCHEMA1 
WHERE (
SELECT TICKETUID
FROM DB.SCHEMA2
WHERE LDKEY = TICKETUID
)
```

How can I compare the `LDKEY` from one schema to the `TICKETUID` of another? I only want to extract data where the key and ticket are equal - all other data I do not need. I can get data out using only one schema successfully, but one dataset `DB.SCHEMA1` is too large to export, so it must be filtered first. How do comparisons across Schemas work in SQL/TOAD? How do I reference other schema from SQL queries?

I have seen similar questions out there, but none seemed to get at this directly.

Comment: Are `schema1` and `schema2` a tables or different schema? It seems that db is schema name and schema1 and schema2 are tables from your query

Comment: One is actually a 'View' and the other is a 'Table' - why they have it that way? I will never know. I actually had some other problems, so I don't even think I need this solution anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be answered using SQL, regardless of whether you use TOAD or not. Add a WHERE clause (or join, depending on the data model) to compare the two values.

```
SELECT LDKEY, LDOWNERTABLE, LDTEXT, LDOWNERCOL
  FROM DB.SCHEMA1 INNER JOIN DB.SCHEMA2 ON LDKEY = TICKETUID
```